# How to bring Autocomplete feature in a CQ5 Archtype Maven project and make eclipse recognize CQ classes like SlingRepository, javax.jcr.Node etc?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aem, spring-tool-suite

I am new to maven. I have followed this link to create a CQ5 maven archtype [Link](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html)

These are the steps that I followed:

1) Execute this command in cmd(windows)

```
mvn archetype:generate     -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/     -DarchetypeGroupId=com.day.jcr.vault     -DarchetypeArtifactId=multimodule-content-package-archetype     -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2     -DgroupId=my-group-id     -DartifactId=mvnproject     -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT     -Dpackage=com.xxx.mvnproject    -DappsFolderName=mvnproject     -DartifactName="My Project"     -DcqVersion="5.5.0"     -DpackageGroup="xxx"
```

2) Imported the project in Eclipse(Spring Tools Suite) as an Existing Maven Project. So I believe that STS already has Maven M2 plugin installed.

3) Executed this command in cmd `mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install`

4) So when I checked the /apps I saw my some stuff got installed in the CQ repository.

**The Problem : In STS(Spring tools suite) the Java files don't have the "Ctrl+space" Autocomplete feature as they are not in java class path. How do I activate the autocomplete feature ?**

Also I don't understand where to place my JSPs. even if I have Jsp how do I get them to compile immediately like in any other "Dynamic Web Project"

**When I click on Run -> install isn't that as good as `mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install`
but when I do this nothing gets installed in the Cq repository**. Please help.

See Directory structure below for reference

[image]
[image]

**Edit : I did something with the maven project and the auto complete feature started working but it doesn't recognise the CQ classes like SlingRepository etc. Any inputs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just information :: I did this. Right Click on project Transform to Faceted project.
And the Java files started being recognised as Java files. I resolved the errors in eclipse by providing the location on the actually jars in .m2 folder so **now I had the auto complete feature**

I however am not able to build the project as some jars aren't being downloaded from the repo.adobe.com I don't undertand why. I have added the correct dependency in the POM. Anyways Thats a differernt issue. I got my auto complete for now thats good.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with eclipse not doing auto-complete because our view module (ui) wasn't included in the build path. With the service module (bundle) it was easy to clear the folders automatically set up and add the correct folder src/main/java in the build path- see comment below. Our project imports differently and began with the cq-blueprints archetype, so each Maven reactor module is shown in the Project Explorer at the same level as the parent. I don't think that matters. In our case, we had a naming issue that required us to add a linked resource in the .project file (code below) This created a resource that allowed us to include the 'components' linked resource in the path.

```
<linkedResources>
       <link>
            <name>components/apps/our-app-name</name>
            <type>2</type>
            <locationURI>PROJECT_LOC/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/our-app-name</locationURI>
       </link>
```

Regarding the second issue. you can run and deploy maven from eclipse by setting up the profile. go into the Run Configurations from Maven menu, and create a configuration using the `autoInstallPackage` profile, and then running that should install and deploy.

For JSP's you can try the jspc maven plugin. But it wasn't necessary for auto-complete. Make sure you're paths are correct for the cq taglibs and the global.jsp for example...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="cq" uri="http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0" %>
<%@include file="../../../../../libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<cq:defineObjects />
```

Comment: How do I add the OSGi Bundle part of this maven archtype in class path. Could you share any useful links (Apart from the official docs, I have read that it is not very detailed) ?

Comment: Try this; Right click on mvnproject, Hover Build Path, Select Configure Build Path, Remove current paths that may have been automatically added if any, Click Add Folder, Select the folder mvnproject/src/main/java (this should be the folder holding your java packages). hope it helps

Comment: @Oliver add the generated bundle to the target platform. Like adding the folder `target` of the project. (Though the bundle install also installs to a separate folder, probably it is best to add that folder.)

Comment: @ChristopherRockwell ::  your comment was helpful but you for got to tell me one very important thing, that **I first have to convert the project to faceted form. Only then I could apply build path options.**